# jQuery: SUM of columns and merge them to one cell (Replace them with SUM result)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

I want to change this table:

[image]

#### Is that possible With jQuery?

If yes, please just send me similar example or any workaround.

EDIT:
I knew how to read all td's

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {

    $.each(this.cells, function(){
        var celltext = $(this).text();
    });

});
```

Also, this how each similar value can be grouped to one cell:

```
var $rows = $('#tableid tbody tr');
var items = [],
    itemtext = [],
    currGroupStartIdx = 0;
$rows.each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var itemCell = $(this).find('td:eq(0)');
    var item = itemCell.text();
    itemCell.remove();
    if ($.inArray(item, itemtext) === -1) {
        itemtext.push(item);
        items.push([i, item]);
        groupRowSpan = 1;
        currGroupStartIdx = i;
        $this.data('rowspan', 1)
    } else {
        var rowspan = $rows.eq(currGroupStartIdx).data('rowspan') + 1;
        $rows.eq(currGroupStartIdx).data('rowspan', rowspan);
    }

});

$.each(items, function(i) {
    var $row = $rows.eq(this[0]);
    var rowspan = $row.data('rowspan');
    $row.prepend('<td rowspan="' + rowspan + '" style="white-space:nowrap;">' + this[1] + '</td>');
});
```

This is PHP Solution so far:

```
foreach($tabledata as $key => $val){
 $rowspan = (count($val) > 1 ? ' rowspan="'.count($val).'" ' : '');
   $spancount = 0;
   foreach($val as $vkey => $vval){
     $spancount++;
      echo '
      <tr>
      ';
       if($spancount == 1){
        echo '
        <td'.$rowspan.'>'.$key.'</td>
        ';
       }
      echo '
      <td>'.$vval[0].'</td>
      ';
      echo '
      <td>'.$vval[1].'</td>
      ';
     if($spancount == 1){
      echo '
      <td'.$rowspan.'>'.$sums[$key].'</td>
      ';
     }
      echo '</tr>
      ';
   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the Name column is always in the right order?

Comment: With 3k+ reputation, surely you should know how to ask a good quesiton by now.

Comment: @Eric: I am confused with this, I do solved by PHP, but I gave-up with jQuery... sorry

Comment: @Akam You "gave up" with it? That would imply you have some code which is incomplete or not working--can you post that (as per Zenith's suggestion)?

Comment: @Zenith: I don't want exact solution, I need only an approach to solve this

Comment: @Akam Much better. I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @Eric: thanks man I hope to help also

Comment: You can improve the question! it's better than to close it while the problem is answered and its not off-topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I took a shot at it. I took the liberty of putting class names into the TDs and TRs, and the JavaScript can be cleaned up a lot, but it does work.

```
var first_row = '<tr class="row"><td class="id">NULL</td></tr>';
var rowCount = 0;
var rowSum = 0;
$.each($('.row'), function (index, curRow) {
    if ($(first_row).find('.id').text() != $(curRow).find('.id').text()) {
        if (rowCount > 1) {
            $(first_row).find('.val').text(rowSum);
            $(first_row).find('.val').attr('rowspan', rowCount).css('background-color','silver');
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                $(first_row).next('.row').find('.val').remove();
            }
        }
        first_row = $(curRow);
        rowSum = 0;
        rowCount = 0;
    }
    rowSum += parseInt($(curRow).find('.val').text());
    rowCount += 1;
});
if (rowCount > 1) {
    $(first_row).find('.val').text(rowSum);
    $(first_row).find('.val').attr('rowspan', rowCount).css('background-color','silver');
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        $(first_row).next('.row').find('.val').remove();
    }
}
```

[Link to Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CErrN/2/)

Comment: brilliant! thanks, I will mention you in my Pray in Ramadhan :)

Comment: Just simple question: in my table there are some cases with more than 5 cells merged, the rowspan count is correct, however, only first three cells removed, after this, the cells not removed. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CErrN/4/

Comment: I missed the primary edge condition.  I've updated the code at http://jsfiddle.net/rDBfv/1/

Comment: Thanks again, I really Appreciate your help, you are much better than whose closed the question, I see that good people always exists everywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, yo said you just wanted a general approach, you don't need code.

Loop over the rows. If col 0 is different from previous, remember this row as the first of a set, and remember col 0's text as the "previous" value.

if col 0 is the same as the previous value, add the content of col 1 to col 1 of the first row of the set, delete col 1 from this row, and increase the rowspan of col 1 in the first row.

One problem in your code:

```
$rows.data("rowspan")
```

should be

```
$this.children("td:eq(1)").attr("rowspan")
```

Comment: Thanks, your idea is similar to posted example. I got a perfect solution on how to start grouping similar names (cell values).